# ADT Plugin for IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, adt

Is there an ADT plugin for ItelliJ Idea? I've been looking everywhere but can't find one. I need it because according to Google's training on developer.android.com I need to "Make sure you install the latest version of the ADT plugin to complete this tutorial." But I don't use eclipse, and don't want to use it.

Comment: Android studio is based on Intelij.

Answer (score 1):

The training is currently written with Eclipse in mind. You will need to translate various Eclipse-specific instructions to other IDEs yourself.

In the case of IntelliJ IDEA, assuming you are on a reasonably recent version, it already has a fair amount of Android integration, just not called "ADT".

Comment: well, the main issue I have is, ActionBarActivity can't be found.

Comment: @afroraydude: `ActionBarActivity` comes from one of [the Android Support libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html). You will need to add that to your project to reference that class.